# Download de arquivo via Ajax

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, mvc, javascript

Em meu projeto Asp.Net MVC 4, tenho uma View com um botão e o seguinte script:

```
<input type="button" value="Teste" id="baixarArquivo" />

<script>

(function () {

    $("#baixarArquivo").off("click").on("click", function () {
        DownloadArquivo();
    });

    function DownloadArquivo() {
        $.ajax({
            beforeSend: function () {
                // Inicia Load
            },
            complete: function () {
                // Finaliza Load
            },
            contentType: 'application/json, charset=utf-8',
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'POST',
            url: '@Url.Action("DownloadArquivo", "MeuController", new { area = "Administrador" })',
            // Parâmetros
            //data: JSON.stringify(
            //    {
            //        Param1: minhaVar,
            //    }),
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.success) {
                    // Baixar arquivo
                } else {
                    alert("Erro! " + data.title + " " + data.error);
                }
            },
            fail: function () {
                alert("Error 007");
            }
        });
    }
})();
</script>
```

No Controller minha Action está da seguinte forma:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult DownloadArquivo()
    {
        try
        {
            byte[] fileBytes = null;

            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(ms))
                {
                    tw.WriteLine("Este é apenas um teste!");

                    tw.Flush();
                    ms.Flush();

                    fileBytes = ms.ToArray();
                }
            }

            return Json(new
            {
                success = true,
                content = fileBytes,
                fileName = "meuArquivo",
                mimeType = System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Text.Plain
            }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Json(new
            {
                success = false,
                error = ex.Message,
                title = "Download"
            }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

    }
```

Como baixar o arquivo caso tudo ocorra bem?

Comment: No success da chamada de `ajax`, faça primeiro um `console.log(data);`, veja se imprime algo.

Answer (score 3):

Você pode utilizar um plugin `JavaScript` chamado [*Download.js*](http://danml.com/download.html), mas ele não tem compatibilidade com versões anteriores do Internet Explorer, apenas a partir do 9.

Outra solução é você abrir um `iframe` para fazer o download, no final das contas é transparente para o usuário.

```
<input type="button" value="Teste" id="baixarArquivo" />
<iframe id="meu-iframe" style="display:none"></iframe>

<script type="text/javascript">

    $("#baixarArquivo").click(function () {
        DownloadArquivo();
    });

    function DownloadArquivo() {
        $('#meu-iframe').attr('src', '@Url.Action("DownloadArquivo", "MeuController", new { area = "Administrador" })');
    }
</script>
```

Espero ter ajudado \o/

Answer (score 1):

Jedaias, o `MVC` possui uma `ViewResult` propria para arquivos, no caso a `FileResult`

Segue abaixo um exemplo completo com o `Upload` e o `Download` do mesmo arquivo através de `AJAX`.

**Model**

```
public class RequestModel
{
    public HttpPostedFileBase Arquivo { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(new { });
    }


    [HttpPost]
    public FileResult SendFile(RequestModel model)
    {
        return File(model.Arquivo.InputStream, model.Arquivo.ContentType, model.Arquivo.FileName);
    }
}
```

**View**

```
<form id="formulario" method="POST" action="@Url.Content("~")Home/SendFile">
    <div>
        <label>
            Arquivo:
            <input id="Arquivo" name="Arquivo" type="file" />
        </label>
    </div>
    <div>
        <input id="enviar" type="submit" />
    </div>
</form>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var formulario = document.getElementById("formulario");
formulario.addEventListener("submit", function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var method = event.target.method;
    var action = event.target.action;
    var data = new FormData(event.target);

    var httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
    httpRequest.open(method, action, true);
    httpRequest.responseType = "blob";
    httpRequest.addEventListener("readystatechange", function (event) {
        if (httpRequest.readyState == 4) {
            var blob = httpRequest.response;

            var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            var link = document.createElement("a");
            var event = new Event("click");
            link.href = url;
            link.download = "<%nome do arquivo%>";
            link.dispatchEvent(event);
            URL.revokeObjectURL(url);
        }
    });

    httpRequest.send(data);
});
```

Se precisar monitorar o progresso do upload/download, faça uso do evento "progress"

```
httpRequest.addEventListener("progress", function (event) {
  if (event.lengthComputable) {
    var percent = event.loaded / event.total;
  }
});
```

O problema de se baixar um arquivo por AJAX, é que não é possivel pegar o nome do Arquivo pelo `XMLHttpRequest.response`, então você vai que setar o nome do arquivo direto no `JavaScript`.