# Download de tabela vinda de retorno de solicitação AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery

#### Cenário teste

Tenho uma página, com `input` "data inicial" e "data final", e um botão "planilha".

O botão chama a função `planilha()`.

Função `planilha()`:

```
function planilha() {

    var dados = $('#meuform').serialize();
    arquivo = "planilha.php";
    $.ajax({
        type:'post',
        data:dados,
        url:arquivo,
        success: function(retorno){      
            ??????????
        },
        error: function(){
            alert('Falha');
        }
    });
}
```

O arquivo `planilha.php` está sendo gerado perfeitamente, e retornando uma tabela pronta.

Esse mesmo arquivo, eu já gero planilha e forço o download, usando:

```
header ("Content-type: application/x-msexcel");
header ("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"{$arquivo}\"" );
```

Mas agora gostaria de fazer direto pelo AJAX.

---

#### Dúvida

Gostaria de fazer o download desse retorno em formato *xls*.

- Existe alguma forma de fazer isso ou terei que gerar a `table` pelo *JS* para conseguir baixá-la?

Comment: da uma olhada neste exemplo, https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/131627/download-de-arquivo-via-ajax?rq=1

Comment: @Lodi Eu não achei nada que me ajudasse nesse link. Uma resposta usa o `document` e não o retorno. E a outra usa `XMLHttpRequest`. Como sei muito pouco de JS posso ter me enganado.

Comment: "Você pode utilizar um plugin JavaScript chamado Download.js, mas ele não tem compatibilidade com versões anteriores do Internet Explorer, apenas a partir do 9." Palavras do Uilque Messias 

segue o link para analise http://danml.com/download.html

Você pode usar a biblioteca ou construir a sua própria, se levar em consideração que o source dela está na home!

Comment: @Lodi Mas ele está usando fazendo download de conteúdo da página, e não do retorno do ajax. Mas vou dar uma olhada sim nessa biblioteca. Mas também gostaria de uma resposta sua, assim ajudaria bastante. Valeu! 

Comment: Nunca fiz download através de ajax, não tenho uma resposta muito precisa, mas acredito que você dando um return no file, já deva dar para tentar fazer o download usando essa biblioteca!

Comment: @Lodi Poderia me dar um exemplo desse `return`? A biblioteca até tem o `ajax fallback`, mas parece que só é para download de arquivo html. Então teria que ver uma mudança...

Comment: eu tentaria assim, na função php, você retorna o arquivo carregado em uma variavel ou uma URL para ele fazer o download do arquivo gerado, e no success você ou abre um link com o download usando _blank para nova pagina da para fazer com jquery, ou usaria essa biblioteca para capturar o arquivo em bits, e depois salvar ele no pc, sacou?

Comment: var url = $(this).attr('href');
window.open(url, '_blank');